Content is not allowed in prolog in running Gradle in Jetpack compose
What is the solution to "Content is not allowed in prolog", in Kotlin Jetpack Compose when running your code. What can I do to solve that?
This happens either on a new "Hello Andriod" code or written code.
The error is failing to allow the gradle(sync) to run my jetpack compose code in Andriod Studio. I have been on this for over 24 hours.

The solution would be remove the content from the prolog. If you need more help then please [edit] your question to add a [mre] so we can have a look what specifically needs to be done.

You probably have an XML file in your project where there is an invalid character in the first line or the <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> is missing at all.

Now am getting the issue when trying to run the app on my Physical Device. How can I solved it please? I really need help.
